# Add comma's in string

Tags: c++, qt

I was wondering how can I set a ',' comma in an int or string? 
For example, I already got this:

```
QString::number(object->number())
```

which will be shown on the UI.

And the number is something like `123456789`, how can I set the format that the string will be `123,456,789`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Checkout the docs on QLocale at http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qlocale.html:

```
QLocale(QLocale::English).toString(123456789);
```

Answer (score 4):

You are looking into [QLocale::toString(int)](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qlocale.html#toString)

```
int i = 123456789;
QLocale l = QLocale::system();
QString s = l.toString(i);
```

Notes:

- Do not use "commas", in every locale (language, country) this is different. See http://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/manual/gettext.html#Aspects for more examples.
- If you use [QString::number()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qstring.html#number-2) you will get a local dependent representation.

Answer (score 1):

maybe: http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/9822-Numbers-with-comma-format
   QString number = QLocale(QLocale::English).toString(123456789, 'f', 2);
(I haven't tested)

Comment: This one doesn't compile for me. That overload of QLocale::toString is intended for float / double and is ambiguous when passing an integer to it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, for sure! Try this:

```
QLocale locale(QLocale::English);
QString string = locale.toString(123456789.21345, 'f');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
double n = 123456789.12345;
QString string = QLocale(QLocale::English).toString(n, 'f', 2);
```

This has worked for me.